# Download zip, unpack, transform content to srt and finally transform str to array

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, subtitle, jszip

To download the zip I'm using `Axios`

```
async getLegendaZip(url) {
try {
  const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' });

  this.unzipLegenda(response.data);
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error);
}
```

}

To unzip the zip I'm using `JSzip`
To do the parse srt to `Array` I am using the lib `Subtitle`

```
unzipLegenda(buf) {
const new_zip = new JSZip();
new_zip.loadAsync(buf)
    .then(function(zip) {
      zip.forEach((relativePath, file) => {
        const arr = parse(file);
        console.log(arr);
      });
    });
```

}

I get this warning in the log

[image: I get this warning in the log]

Comment: is "file" a string?

Comment: It's a legend.srt

Comment: This if the actual buff is unzip the way I expect it to. 

Comment: The parser expects a string. So you have get the contents from this file.